# Lubuntu: Remapping caps to backspace: 15.10 or 16.04

Tags: command-line, keyboard, lubuntu, keyboard-layout

I've spent more time then I care to admit, attempting to change caps to backspace in Lubuntu on a spare computer (15.10), cause I want to switch to lubuntu as my main linux (with 16.04). Basically once you have got used to using caps as backspace you have ruined your ability to use normal computers. I don't recommend it, but I wouldn't go back. Here is what I have tried based on less detailed answers.

```
$ sudo setxkbmap -option caps:backspace
```

also tried editing /etc/default/keyboard to have the same option

also tried to add it to the options field in the keyboard switcher panel

Logged out and in testing before and after even adding the setxkbmap line to startup and restarting

Is there a guide somewhere on the exact syntax of using setxkbmap? The man goes over options but doesn't show syntax for various keymappings, the main guide link is broken

Is there a more reliable way (maybe simple graphical way) to do this other than setxkbmap?

Answer (score 0):

In dconf-editor: **org >> gnome >> desktop >> input-sources >> xkb-options** list.
dconf-editor has GUI.
Autostart scripts not needed if you go this way.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have Lubuntu any more to test and verify, but If I ever go back to it I'll try this out.